# How to get string inside QLineEdit (PyQt5 and Python)?

Tags: python, pyqt, qlineedit

I was looking for an answer to this beginner question but only found long or complicated ones. I have a list of QLineEdits and now I want to get the string in one of them, how is this done?

```
my_list = []
a = QLineEdit()
a.setText("text1")
my_list.append(a)

b = QLineEdit()
b.setText("text2")
my_list.append(b)
```

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain.

Comment: I feel the downvote was done because the answer to the question can be found quite easily. More info - https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Which button do you want to get the text from?

Comment: @Ashish Nitin Patil please provide a link to a source which does this. The PyQt documentation and wiki - files that I looked at were long and as a beginner it is hard to know where to find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting result from element with idx `i`:

```
answer = my_list[i].text()
```